# PHP query not working as intended. Insert statement runs when an error should be shown

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if I could get some help as to where I am going wrong in the register page for the website I am creating.

When the user is creating an account a check is made to ensure that the username and email they enter has not already been taken. If neither is taken then the information they enter is entered into an SQL table I have set up. At the moment though this is not working how it should be, if an email address has already been taken then an error is show but if the username is already taken, no error is shown and the info is inserted into the SQL table.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<body>
 <?php

    //if form has been submitted process it

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



        //collect form data

        extract($_POST);

        
            if($name==''){

            $error[] = 'Please enter your name.';

        }



        if($username ==''){

            $error[] = 'Please enter the username you would like.';

        }

        if($email==''){

            $error[] = 'Please enter your email address.';

        }
        
            if($age < 18){

            $error[] = 'You are too young to create an account with this site.';

        }
        
        if ($age==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter your age.';
        }
        
          if($email==''){

            $error[] = 'Please enter your email address.';

        }


        if($password ==''){

            $error[] = 'Please enter your password.';

        }



        if($passwordConfirm ==''){

            $error[] = 'Please confirm the password.';

        }



        if($password != $passwordConfirm){

            $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';

        }
        

        
        if(!isset($error)){

            $query = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?');

            $query->bindValue( 1, $username );

            $query->execute();



            if( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query

   
            echo '<p class="error" align="center">An account has already been made using this username</p>';


            }
            
            $query = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?');

            $query->bindValue( 1, $email );

            $query->execute();



            if( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query

   
            echo '<p class="error" align="center">An account has already been made using this email address</p>';


            }

            else {


                try {

                $hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


                //insert into database

  
                $stmt = $dbconn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,name,password,email,role,age,passwordchange) VALUES (:username, :name, :password, :email, :role, :age, :passwordchange)') ;

                $stmt->execute(array(

                    ':username' => $username,

                    ':name' => $name,
                    
                    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                    
                    ':email' => $email,

                    ':role' => "user",
                    
                    ':age' => $age,
                    
                    ':passwordchange' => 0

                  

                ));
                    //redirect to login page

                header('Location: login.php');

                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo $e->getMessage();

            }           

            }

        }
    
    }
            //check for any errors

    if(isset($error)){

        foreach($error as $error){

            echo '<p class="error" align="center">'.$error.'</p>';

        }

    }
    
    ?>

<div class = "register">

<form action='' method='post' align = "center">
         <h2>Register an account</h2>
    <p><label>Name</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['name'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Username</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Email Address</label><br />

        <input type='email' name='email' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email'];}?>'></p>
                
        <p><label>Age</label><br />

        <input type='age' name='age' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['age'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Password</label><br />

        <input type='password' name='password' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['password'];}?>'></p>



        <p><label>Confirm Password</label><br />

        <input type='password' name='passwordConfirm' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['passwordConfirm'];}?>'></p>

        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'></p>
        
        <p>Already a member? <a href="login.php">Log in</a></p>

    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Some more information:

if I swap the username and email queries around then an error will show if the username has already been taken but not with the email.

If I don't have the else statement with the code for inserting into the database then both queries will return an error. I am just really confused as to where I have gone wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:

So I am still confused as to why this isn't working, I have done this like I have done for other projects and it works fine so I don't know why it's not working here.

With the comment suggesting to put else with the second if statement for the email check, I then get an error saying "unexpected else". So what else can I do to fix this?

Comment: There may be another issue, but check the script logic: If the username exists, you `echo` the message, but the execution continues. Also, don't do `extract($_POST)`!

Comment: What's wrong with using extract($_POST)?

Comment: You have a logical issue in your code in if else, first if works fine and for second if, if it is false then it goes to else condition. So to fix it, use else if for your second if (which is email check)

Comment: Currently, your code is working in this flow, if the username matched just echo a message, then it will check for the email if matched, echo a message and the else part will not work, if email not matched, the else part will work regardless of the username check.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you Amir!

Comment: @AmirHussain how should I place the else? as when I put it in the second if statement I get an unexpected else error

Comment: `extract($_POST)` will... _extract_ every element of `$_POST`. You don't know what's in there. You're giving the user full control of all the symbols in that scope; he could replace any variable previously defined, or set a variable you didn't initialize properly and you weren't expecting to come from `$_POST`. It's exactly like the old  `register_globals` (completely removed for a reason). 
Explicitly get only the elements you are expecting. In an ideal world, you'd also want to use `filter_input()`.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you. I'll look to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, and yes it was a logic issue that causing the problem. This is how I am now doing it and it works perfectly:

```
$userQuery = $dbconn->prepare( 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?');

            $userQuery->bindValue( 1, $username );

            $userQuery->execute();

            $emailQuery = $dbconn->prepare( 'SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?' );

            $emailQuery->bindValue( 1, $email );

            $emailQuery->execute();

            
         if($userQuery->rowCount() > 0 && $emailQuery->rowCount() > 0  ) {
            
            echo '<p class="error" align="center">An account has already been made using this username</p>';
            echo '<p class="error" align="center">An account has already been made using this email address</p>';

        }



            else if( $userQuery->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query

            echo '<p class="error" align="center">An account has already been made using this username</p>';

        }
    
        else if( $emailQuery->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query

            echo '<p class="error" align="center">An account has already been made using this email address</p>';

            }
```